# how to find the source code that produce the Resources in Chrome Inspect Element

Tags: javascript, php

If you look at the following site http://styles.my/thestar/ , the inspect element using chrome shows a 404 for http://shopping.thestar.com.my/image/.

How can I find or trace back the code that producing this error?

Comment: How can you trace back a 404 **File not found** error? Where would you trace it, the file doesn't exist, end of story !

Comment: I actually see a 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)' on http://styles.my/thestar/image/

Comment: yeah, thats is the thing I stuck..Don't know where to look for the codes that calling this path, cause it doesn't shows the actual file it trying to retrieve.

Comment: the first file is trying to load it's the favicon from that path. You have to fix permission in the server side or avoid load resources from that path.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a a 403 error.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Has to be something about permission in the server side. And this is the correct URL for this resource http://styles.my/thestar/image/

Make sure you ask with the correct info :)